# OpenJPA does not create DB2 tables when deploying on Websphere Application Server

Tags: db2, websphere, openjpa

I deployed my ear file on Websphere Application server V7.0 and start the application. However, it does not auto create table to my database DB2 and don't have any error message.

Please see my persitence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="xcrm_ejb" >
<jta-data-source>jdbc/xcrm</jta-data-source>
<non-jta-data-source>jdbc/non_xcrm</non-jta-data-source>
<mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
<class>ch.xpertline.xcrm.entity.base.BaseEntity</class>
<class>ch.xpertline.xcrm.entity.Address</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=INFO,SQL=TRACE,File=./dist/jpaEnhancerLog.log,Runtime=INFO,Tool=INFO"/>
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72"/>
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My orm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit-metadata>
<persistence-unit-defaults>
<schema>soreco</schema>
</persistence-unit-defaults>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try sending in an application request. I don't think synchronize mappings is triggered until the first EntityManager is created.